# How can I create two full-width headers on the top of the page without position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, header

I need to create two full-width headers but I can't seem to find a way to do them without using position absolute because if i use position:absolute, I can't use margin-bottom, which I need. What can I do?

This is what I have tried:

```
<div class="header1">
</div>

<div class="header2">
</div>

.header1 {
background-color: red;
    margin-top: 110px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.header2 {
background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 150px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why it is `//div`?  Also what browser are you using?

Comment: @davidstarkey sorry that was my type.  Browser? Firefox on Mac.

Comment: you want them to be on top of each other - one hidden like that?

Comment: @scottselby, the first one should stick to the top and the second one should have 50px gap between the first one.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JxMVc/

Comment: @heavy Thanks.  I used your code in my solution but it's adding space from the top of the first one.  I also used your margin and padding: 0 but it still gives me a gap from the top of the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding the problem correctly, but

```
body {
    margin:0
}
.header1 {
    background-color: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header2 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Will give you 2 full width headers

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/LbzWZ/)

Comment: Thanks! Almost there with your code but for me it seems to be adding a space from the top.  NOt sure why.

Comment: probably needing to reset `margin` and `padding` on your `html` and `body` tags. If you have content in the first div shich has margins that would also push it down. [see this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/LbzWZ/1/) if you remove the `margin:0` from the `h1` you get a space above the div

Comment: THanks.  I never thought a header can be created that easily without what I have above.  I a jr front-end dev so learning new stuff!